# Super search against multiple fields & wildcard

Tags: c#, linq, wildcard

I have an option on my webpage for a 'super search'. This simply does a search across multiple properties for a match. Over time it has grown from a simple exact text match to checking for individual words in any order and and treating underscores like spaces and multiple spaces like single spaces and it's now a real mess and doesn't cater for every situation!

**Current Linq filtering code:**

```
private List<StockRecordItem> GetCoreSearchResults()
{
    //strip multiple spaces
    string searchString = Regex.Replace(uxTxtSuperSearch.Text.Trim(), " +", " ");


    List<StockRecordItem> stocks = StoresPortalDataAccessHelper.GetAllStockRecords(uxLocation.SelectedValue)
    //Check no super search provided
    .Where(s => 
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)
        || (
                // Check Stock description - treating underscores and ampersands as spaces
                searchString.ToLower().Split().All(w => s.Description.ToLower().Replace(",", " ").Replace("_", " ").Replace("&", " ").Replace("-", " ").Split().Contains(w))

                // Check Stock Notes - treating underscores and ampersands as spaces
                || (s.Notes != null && searchString.ToLower().Split().All(w => s.Notes.ToLower().Replace(",", " ").Replace("_", " ").Replace("&", " ").Replace("-", " ").Split().Contains(w)))

                // Check other single word fields
                || s.StockId.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || s.Description.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || s.Notes.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || s.Warehouse.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || s.IsRestricted.ToString().Contains(searchString.ToLower().Replace("yes", "True").Replace("no", "False"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Manufacturer) && s.Manufacturer.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                || s.RelatedEquipments.Any(e => e.EquipmentNumber.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                || s.RelatedEquipments.Any(e => e.EquipmentId.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        )

        // Part Number filter
        && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uxTxtPartNumber.Text) || s.PartNumber.Contains(uxTxtPartNumber.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))

        // Warehouse filter
        && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uxWarehouse.SelectedItem.Text) || s.Warehouse.Contains(uxWarehouse.SelectedItem.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        )
    .ToList();

    return stocks;
}
```

**Functionality Required:**

- Search for exact match
- Case insensitive
- Multiple spaces treated as single spaces
- Underscores and ampersands treated as single spaces
- 'MySearchString' will match 'MySearchString record item' or 'MySearchString'
- 'My Search String' will match on 'String SEARCH My' or any other combination of those words. (Note: this doesn't match 'string search', every word must be present)
- Anything else I may not have mentioned that is good practice in a search solution?

**Questions:**

1. How can I clean up the above code for readability/performance?
2. How can I add in a wildcard option. i.e. Search string 'My%Item' returns 'my item' and 'myItem'

Comment: I think full-text search is a good way to do such kind of searches. You can write your own full-text search queries in a stored proc. Here is a [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) for Sql server full text search.

Comment: What about using recursion to go through all of the properties on your object that are strings? Might be easier than having the same code for each property.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".